# How to get the percentage change a stock price has changed between specific days in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, stock

For Example,

I'd like to get the price change for FaceBook, FB, for the days 1st March 2019 and 28th March 2019?

I've gotten this far, but it does not seem to be working.

```html
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B3,"price")/INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(B3,"price",TODAY()-7),2,2)-1
```

Comment: What's in `B3` ?

Comment: And what error are you getting?  Please update your question with more specific details.  Ideally, sharing a sample sheet showing the problem is almost always helpful.  See this guide: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help: trying to get sector data for stocks, the change percentages over certain specific dates: here is the shared sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tFF_rFUdwEGCYvXuLfQqxpaiKRn51e1UJsHSanP9qPk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

`GOOGLEFINANCE()` formula's result is an expanded array. You have to use a second formula for the percentage calculation taking the price data from your desired dates from the expanded array(s).

**Reference:**

- [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)